# How can I open a Visual Studio solution without loading all of its projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, solution, suo

I have big solution in Visual Studio that has some Android, Windows Phone and iOS Xamarin projects. Unfortunately, Visual Studio **hangs** (for hours) when it tries to load the whole solution. It worked fine as long as I usually only loaded either the Android or the iOS project (and plug-in project), but not both at the same time.

Unfortunately, I changed it and now I can't load the solution anymore. I read that settings like these are stored in the .suo file, but I have no idea how I change it (and disable loading the Android projects for example). How can I close certain projects without doing this after the whole solution loaded?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462384.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the sln file in notepad and just delete the projects you dont need.
But to make sure you don't mess things up I would suggest making a backup of your sln file.

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the PRJ file that you're interested in all by itself.